# Let f be holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f^2$ a polynomial, show that f must be a polynomial too.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I've tried to derive $f^2$ and use the formulae for the product of two infinite series, but haven't got much out of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If $f^2$ is a polynomial, it is bounded in modulus near $\infty$ by a function of the form $|z|^N$ for some $N$. Show that $f$ also has a bound of that form and then prove that an entire function bounded by a polynomial is a polynomial.